# Deploying ARM Template with override parameters in Azure DevOps is converting int values as string type

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am passing some override parameters to my Data Factory ARM template deployment step in an Azure DevOps yaml file and one global parameter in particular is specified as an 'int' type within the generated ARM template.

[image]

When I attempt to pass the override parameter from a variable group, Azure DevOps keeps changing it to a string instead of keeping it as an int type resulting in an error within the pipeline.

[image]

I've tried a few things listed below but none have worked.

**Deploy task:**

```
  - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
    displayName: ARM Template Deployment
    inputs:
      azureResourceManagerConnection: 
      subscriptionId: 
      resourceGroupName: 
      location:
      csmFile:
      csmParametersFile:
      overrideParameters: >
        -factoryName ${{ parameters.dataFactoryName }}
        ${{ parameters.overrideParameters }}
```

**Variable in the variable group:**

[image]

**Doesn't work:**

```
variables:
  - group: test-group

...

    jobs:
      - template: datafactory/create-release.yml@templates
        parameters:
          dataFactoryName: asdfasdf
          overrideParameters: >
            -default_properties_LogoAssetId_value $(default_properties_LogoAssetId_value_Stage)
```

**Doesn't work:**

```
variables:
  - group: test-group

...

    jobs:
      - template: datafactory/create-release.yml@templates
        parameters:
          dataFactoryName: asdfasdf
          overrideParameters: >
            -default_properties_LogoAssetId_value "[int(parameters($(default_properties_LogoAssetId_value_Stage)))]"
```

---

**EDIT**:

Here is a snippet of datafactory/create-release.yml

I think the issue is that I set it as a "string" type. However, I don't know an alternative way to handle passing the override parameters as a mixture of string and int values.

```
  - name: overrideParameters
    type: string


jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy ARM Template
    environment: Prod
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
            - template: steps/step-arm-template-deploy.yml
              parameters:
                subscriptionId: ${{ parameters.subscriptionId }}
                targetResourceGroupName: ${{ parameters.targetResourceGroupName }}
                targetDataFactorylocation: ${{ parameters.targetDataFactorylocation }}
                targetDataFactoryName: ${{ parameters.targetDataFactoryName }}
                overrideParameters: ${{ parameters.overrideParameters }}
```

Comment: Can you try changing the override parameter to below and check once 
overrideParameters: >
  -default_properties_LogoAssetId_value $(int(default_properties_LogoAssetId_value_Stage))

Comment: Download the expanded azure-pipeline-expanded.yml file after the job has been completed. Also can you show the parameter definition in `datafactory/create-release.yml@templates` for the `overrideparameters` My gut tells me you have an issue with passing in the entire key value pair. (i.e. the name of the override parameters and the int)

Comment: Unfortunately I still receive the error that it is a string and not an integer

Comment: I updated my question with ```datafactory/create-release.yml```. After looking at the type I set for the parameter I think I found the cause of my issue. But now I don't know the best way to allow the parameter to handle both string and int values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround for now is casting my parameter in DataFactory as an int like this

`@int(pipeline().globalParameters.LogoAssetId)`

While not ideal, it allows me to continue to use my template as-is.

Answer (score 0):

I created one sample parameter with type set to int and added it in my azure repository like below:-

I have referred the ADF ARM template from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-resource-manager-template)

[image]

```json
"Default_properties_log": {
      "type" : "int",
      "defaultvalue" : 1234
```

And I used output method at the end of my ARM template like below:-

[image]

```json
"outputs": { 
    "parametertested" : {"type": "int",
    "value": "[parameters('Default_properties_log')]"}
    }
```

When I added the below value in my release pipeline override parameter, I received the same error code as yours:-

**Error:-**

[image]

```
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'Default_properties_log' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Integer', but received a value of type 'String'. Please see [https://aka.ms/arm-create-parameter-file](https://aka.ms/arm-create-parameter-file) for usage details.'.
```

As In my ARM file I have mentioned the type as int but I was passing value in the format below, I received the error above:-

$(int(Default_properties_log))

[image]

But when I use "12345" or 1234 both will work the error did not appear and the ADF with storage account got deployed successfully in my Azure Portal, Refer below:-

[image]

**My release yaml pipeline script:-**

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'xxxx'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxxd6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7'
    resourceGroupName: siliconrg421rg09
    location: 'Australia East'
    csmFile: azdeploy.json
    overrideParameters: '-dataFactoryName "xxx" -location "AustraliaEast" -Default_properties_log "1234" -storageAccountName "xxxx" -blobContainerName "[format(''blob{0}'', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

One alternative is to create parameters.json file and add all your ARM template parameters inside it and then change the type in parameters.json and override the value in your release pipeline. Make sure the type you specify whether int or string should match the value. As, Override parameter feature will only change the value of the parameter not its type. It will read the type from your ARM template json or parameters.json.

**My parameters.json file sample:-**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "default_properties_LogAssetId_value": {
            "type": "int",
            "value": 12345
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

**Release.yaml with parameters.json file:-**

```yaml
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'xxxx'
    subscriptionId: 'xxxxx-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7'
    resourceGroupName: siliconrg421rg09
    location: 'Australia East'
    csmFile: azdeploy.json
    csmParametersFile: parameters.json
    overrideParameters: '-dataFactoryName "xxxx" -location "AustraliaEast" -Default_properties_log "1234" -storageAccountName "xxxx" -blobContainerName "[format(''blob{0}'', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]" -default_properties_LogAssetId_value 0987'
```

**Reference:-**

[AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 - ARM template deployment v3 task | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines)

Comment: This was insightful thank you. A bit different than my circumstance, however, because I am using yaml templates. I found a workaround for now but if I revisit this in the future, I will probably have to switch to passing in an object and looping over the 'n' amount of passed in override parameters.