# array of object from powershell script into arm template giving error

Tags: azure, powershell, templates

So this is kind of driving me crazy. I want to create some firewall rules for a cosmos DB using arm template (cosomos were already deployed also with templates). Those parameters come from the output of a PowerShell script as an array of objects like this:

```
#start the array
$ipObjects = @()

#the Powershell script commands....

$ipObjects += $ipPrefixObject
$jsonOutput = $ipObjects | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
$jsonOutput.GetType()
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputArray;isOutput=true]$jsonOutput"
```

so the output of $ipobjects is:

```
[
    {
        "name":  "ip1",
        "IpAddress":  "1.2.3.4"
    },
    {
        "name":  "ip2",
        "IpAddress":  "6.6.6.6"
    },
    {
        "name":  "ip3",
        "IpAddress":  "4.4.4.4"
    }
    
]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------

True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

so it´s an object type.

but when I pass this into arm template like this (this is later run by AZDO pipeline):

```
overrideParameters:    -firewallRules "$(outputArray)"


"firewallRules": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Array of firewall rules"
        }
    },
```

I´m getting:

```
the provided value for the template parameter 'firewallRules' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Array', but received a value of type 'String'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-create-parameter-file for usage details.'.
```

I also tried to just pass the array object just like it is without the convert-to-Json. This gives me type object and the following values:

```
     IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
    -------- -------- ----                                     --------
    
        True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


IpAddress : 1.2.3.4
name      : ip1


IpAddress : 6.6.6.6
name      : ip2


IpAddress : 4.4.4.4
name      : ip3
```

this is also giving me same error:

```
eployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'firewallRules' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Array', but received a value of type 'String'. Pl
```

So how do you basically send a PowerShell array of objects to an arm template? I wasn´t able to find much documentation about this. why is expecting string type if I set it to array?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The provided value for the template parameter 'firewall Rules' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Array' but received a value of type 'String':

The issue is not only with the data `type` but it occurs due to handling of variables and parameters by ADO. Though you give type of the parameter as an `array`, ADO treats all variables or parameters as a `string` by default.

I have done a below workaround to resolve your issue.

*Modified PowerShell Script:*

```
$ipObjects = @(
    @{
        "name" = "ip1"
        "IpAddress" = "1.2.3.4"
    },
    @{
        "name" = "ip2"
        "IpAddress" = "6.6.6.6"
    },
    @{
        "name" = "ip3"
        "IpAddress" = "4.4.4.4"
    }
)

$json = $ipObjects | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputArray;isOutput=true]$json
```

[image]

In ARM template, there is a function called [`JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-object#json) which is used to convert the string again back into a `Json` object. While passing parameters from PowerShell to ARM, use this function to avoid conflicts with the data types in ADO.

```bash
"parameters": {
    "firewallRules": {
        "type": "array",
        "defaultValue": [],
        "metadata": {
            "description": ""
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "convertedvalues": "[json(parameters('firewallRules'))]"
}
```

Alternatively, I would suggest you create`parameters.json` file and add all your ARM template parameters inside it, change the type in `parameters.json` and override the value in your release pipeline.

Make sure the type you specify whether `int or string` should match the value. As, Override parameter point will only change the value of the parameter not its type. It'll read the type from your ARM template `Json` or `parameters.json`.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-resource-manager-template-deployment-v3?view=azure-pipelines) for more relevant information on the above.

You can also refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76636607/19785512) by @SiddheshDesai for the workaround of similar issue.

Comment: sorry for delay @jahnavi but I still receive same error: "he provided value for the template parameter 'firewallRules' is not valid. Expected a value of type 'Array', but received a value of type 'String"  I think that the error is while passing the string to the first "firewallRules" in arm template. from AZDO task...and it doesn´t continue till the json function to tranform it. Is this the only way? Also if I add this parameter in the parameters.json would it be any difference? I don use a parameters.json but for other already know parameters. This parameters I´m using now are dynamics .

Comment: also what did you mean by "change the type in parameters.json and override the value in your release pipeline.". instead of array I should change it for string ?
If I change parameter type from "array" to "string" and then I use the json function, I´m getting: "'The template variable 'convertedfirewallRules' is not valid: Unable to evaluate the template language function 'json'. The argument provided is not a valid JSON string."

Comment: What is the argument you are providing? @Zucoa