# Azure Data Factory/Dev Ops. Space in ARM template parameter over ride

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have a data factory that I am trying to deploy using Dev Ops. The release pipeline use the ARM Template deployment step. When I click the Edit Override template parameters button I get some of the parameters that I was expecting, but I am also getting parameters with a space. This breaks the deployment process.

I have hunted through the code trying to find these spurious parameters. I have also been through the code and have removed any spaces just in case.

How can I find and remove these

Comment: 1. " I am also getting parameters with a space" - Can you share a screenshot to help us understand your issue more clearly? 2. Please check whether there are spaces in the name of your parameter. If there is, you cannot directly override it using "Override template parameters" option in the task, since a name with spaces cannot be recognized as a complete string. You need to create a new parameter json file and override the parameters in this new file. Then set this new json file as "Template parameters".

Comment: 3. If there isn't any space in the name of your parameter, create a new release pipeline and add ARM template deployment task again. Then check if there is the same issue. Also, ensure the default branch of your artifact is `adf_publish`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ziyang Liu-MSFT. The overrideParameters: will give error if you use anything apart from string example integer or space.

You can refer my [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76624358/deploying-arm-template-with-override-parameters-in-azure-devops-is-converting-in/76636607#76636607) which utilizes override parameter in ADF ARM Template deployment via Release and YAML pipeline.

The easiest way for you to Find the spaces in the parameters.json file is to ***Visit your Azure Repo > parameters.json file > Click ctrl + f or ctrl + shift + f to enable Find option on the Repository select > * option (Use regular Expression> Type - \s and all the spaces in the file are highlighted:-***

***Output:-***

[image]